# Getting the <a> link to appear correctly

Tags: css, class, html

The page I'm working on is right here: http://jplentertainment.com/webdev/parallax/1.HTML/djs.html

When I click on the blue boxes, a larger box appears. I would like to have a link inside the larger box that you can click on to go to another page. Here's the code so far:

```
  <a href="html-pics/foliio-big/ff-2.jpg" class="col_1-3 gal">
      <img src="html-pics/folio-small/ff-2.jpg" alt="" />
      <div class="mask"></div>
      <div class="desc">
        <h4>Branding Photography 2</h4>
        <div class="desc_text">
          <p>sample text,</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
```

I would like to put a link within the `<p>` tags if possible

Comment: What exactly does "appearing correctly" mean? What are you specifically having a problem with?

Answer (score 0):

does this work?
`<p><a href="link_path" >link_title</a></p>`